Embedding Spline design into React
I keep getting this error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')
    at ue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49456:19)
    at xe (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49586:36)
    at Object.or [as jsx] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49532:16)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49909:32
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24280:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:27529:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29590:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14536:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14580:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14637:35)

All my code is:
import React from "react";
import Spline from "@splinetool/react-spline";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/o3v1HPnOwXUx88B6/scene.splinecode" />
    </div>
  );
}


and I'm getting that error, I've tried checking videos or even docs and found nothing. I've assured that the root of the problem is the  because whenever I remove it out of the code, the web preview is back to normal.

If that is all your code, then where is the import Spline from ... that would be required?

Solution has been found for that :
To resolve the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')" issue, update your dependencies to the following versions:
"@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.6", "@splinetool/runtime": "^1.4.5"
Update your package.json and run npm install or yarn install to apply the changes.

I've tried updating/installing the npm package for spline again setting their versions to "@splinetool/react-spline": "^3.0.3", "@splinetool/runtime": "^1.4.5",. i also tried setting the version of the @splinetool/react-spline" to 2.2.6 as stated in your answer and im still getting the same error

On your package.json file, you have to set first "@splinetool/react-spline": "^2.2.6", "@splinetool/runtime": "^1.4.5" and then, put the following command in your terminal : run npm install to set the changes. (to downgrade from the version 3.0.3 to the 2.2.6).
Don't forget to import Spline on your project :
import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';
Restart the server and see the change on a private navigation to be sure that nothing are saved in the navigator cache files.

I have the same issue, I have installed @splinetool/runtime and @splinetool/react-spline, and import in my project like this :
import React from "react";
import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/o3v1HPnOwXUx88B6/scene.splinecode" />
  );
}

